# Avoid custom lamda function for Ramdajs map

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Array of functions, which is mapped over, is being invoked using fat arrow syntax.

```
import R from 'ramda';

const arrFn = [R.multiply(2), R.identity, R.add(3)];

const testData = 2;

// is there way to avoid custom lamda fn
const result = R.map((x) => x(testData))(arrFn);

console.log('result', result);
```

Are there any **ramda.js** helper fns which can avoid the arrow syntax?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-dylcrz)

Comment: Why do you want to avoid this?

Comment: @DanielA.White, trying to be point free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`applySpec`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#applySpec) for this.  It's not well-documented to handle arrays; its only example is an object.  But it works fine for arrays of functions, just as it does for something like `applySpec ({foo: multiply (2), bar: {baz: identity, qux: add (3)}}) (2)`  yielding `{foo: 4, bar: {baz: 2, qux: 5}}`.  Here it would just be:

```js
const {applySpec, multiply, identity, add} = R

const arrFn = [multiply (2), identity, add (3)]
const testData = 2

console .log (applySpec (arrFn) (testData))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

You could also use [`juxt`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#juxt) (short for "juxtapose" -- don't ask!) but that is not one of Ramda's better-designed functions.

```js
const {juxt, multiply, identity, add} = R

const arrFn = [multiply (2), identity, add (3)]
const testData = 2

console .log (juxt (arrFn) (testData))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: juxt: list of functions to a *list of values*, i had skipped that because of *list of values*, but its seems to work for single item, thanks

Comment: As I said, not well designed.  Nor is it well documented.  Think of it as `(fns) => (...args) => fns .map (fn => fn (...args))`  "list of values" is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```js
const result = R.map(R.apply(R.__, [testData]))(arrFn);
```

Using [the gap specifier](https://ramdajs.com/0.19.0/docs/#__) `R.__` and [`R.apply`](https://ramdajs.com/0.19.0/docs/#apply)

Maybe you can go somewhere with [flip](https://ramdajs.com/0.19.0/docs/#flip), I could only get as far as

```js
const result = R.map(R.flip(R.apply)([testData]))(arrFn);
```

which is neither more terse nor more readable.

Comment: ya its makes its cryptic, i was hoping some helper fn like reverseFnArg

Comment: @vito yes I understand. I couldn't find anything like that though sadly.